# Assigning an external drive a letter in windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, external-hard-drive

I recently reformatted my Windows XP Pro machine and now I can't access my external hard drive. In ***computer management*** the drive shows up and says it is healthy.  If I right click the ***assign a drive letter*** option is disabled.

The device is signed with Buffalo's Secure LockWare so this could be why.  I will try and sort this out in the meantime, but when I used this drive last it would appear in my computer before I could enter the password for access so I'm confused.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Does that partition has a file system that Windows can recognise? Maybe the encryption system used a special partition type to prevent the OS from accidentally mounting the drive and destroy the encrypted data.

Comment: possibly, the FileSystem column is the only one thats blank, and the only other drive like that is my linux drive. I guess i need to get the secure lock ware software working to before i can mount, thx

Comment: I got it working! just reinstalled the secure lock software and all is good :)

Comment: This mean case is closed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sound like you will need to decrypt the drive to mount it, did it come with any software. Maybe you can download it from there website. Sometimes it may show a virtual cd drive in my computer with software on.